# How to send data to AWS Lambda function from golang?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I have a AWS Lambda function written in node.js. I need to send some data to it from golang. Can't find a tutorial. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using AWS Go API, the API docs for lambda package are on:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/lambda/

See https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/ for the links to the "Getting Started" and GitHub repository.